SQLAlchemy: records on association table are not correctly created (association object and proxy approach)
I'm working on a small cycling community project that uses Flask and SQLAlchemy, with MySQL as db.
The ORM isn't complex one, but I tried to give it some flexibility. Four tables in total, but at the core are three tables (for users, challenges and mileage), users and challenges tables are connected in many-to-many relationship to each other via association object instead of association table (I thought it will simplify the model, as I can use that object to store mileage-per-challenge for each user too, instead of having a fifth table). I'll be attaching the full model at the end of the post, for ease of read.
I'm having issues when I'm trying to dump some generated test entries into yet empty database.
First, I do this:
    with app_context:
        db.session().add_all(faked_challenges)
        db.session().add_all(faked_users)
        db.session.flush()
        db.session.commit()

It works and I see users and challenges records appearing in the db. There are still no connections between them (mileage table stays empty).
When I try to create the many-to-many mappings, that's when trouble begins. First, I do this:
    with app_context:
        chal = models.Challenge.query.filter_by(id = 2).first()
        user = models.User.query.filter_by(id = 4).first()

        user.challenges.append(chal)

Then I commit:
        db.session.flush()
        db.session().commit()

I expect this code to map challenge with id=2 to user with id=4 in one go (that's what association proxy is for, if I'm not mistaken). Instead, it always maps the user I pass via the user variable to challenge with id=1, no matter what actual challenge object is referenced by the chal variable (1 is default that is passed to constructor of mileage table for challengeId column, I've confirmed that it actually uses that default all the time for some reason).
Example record:
mysql> select * from mileagePerchallengesTbl;
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| id | userId | challengeId | challengeName | totalDistancePerChallengeKm | contextData |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
|  1 |      4 |           1 | NULL          |                           0 | null        |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+-------------+

But at least it works this way. If in the code above I use chal.users.append(user) instead of user.challenges.append(chal) it throws a cryptic error when it reaches session.flush() step:
MySQLdb.IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tangodown$bbsitedb`.`milagePerchallengesTbl`, CONSTRAINT `milagePerchallengesTbl_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `usersTbl` (`id`))')
...
  File "/home/tangodown/.virtualenvs/my_bb_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 261, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: <exception str() failed>

I can't see any issues with foreign key in my ORM, there shouldn't be any problems with mappings as entries already exist in db and primary keys are generated.
Moreover, I can't understand why, while almost symmetrical, this many-to-many relationship works in one direction, and fails in the other. I was expecting these two lines:
        chal.users.append(user)
        user.challenges.append(chal)

..to produce exactly the same result (a mapping via mileage table) and be completely inter-exchangeable. But one works (though incorrectly), and other doesn't. How is it possible, what am I missing here?
The model:
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import AssociationProxy

class Base(db.DeclarativeBase):
    #this will make the base class abstract, so it won't be mapped to a table.
    __abstract__ = True
    pass

class User(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, email=None, password=None, givenName=None, sn=None, totalDistanceKm=None, groups=None, isActive=False, contextData=None, userAvatarPath=None):
        self.email  = email
        self.password = password
        self.givenName = givenName
        self.sn = sn
        self.totalDistanceKm = totalDistanceKm
        self.groups = groups
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.contextData = contextData
        self.userAvatarPath = userAvatarPath

    __tablename__ = "usersTbl"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    givenName = db.Column(db.String(100))
    sn = db.Column(db.String(100))
    totalDistanceKm = db.Column(db.Float, server_default=text("0.0"))
    groups = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=False)
    isActive = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    contextData = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=True)
    userAvatarPath = db.Column(db.String(150))
    rides = db.relationship('Ride', backref='usersTbl', lazy=True)

    mileage = db.relationship('MileagePerChallenge', back_populates='user', lazy=True)
    challenges = association_proxy('mileage', 'challengesTbl')


    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User "{self.email}">'

class Ride(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, rideGPXPath=None, rideName=None, distanceKm=None, duration=None, rideDateTime=None, uploadDateTime=None, gpxHash=None, ownerId=1, contextData=None, ridePlottedMapPath=None):
        self.rideGPXPath = rideGPXPath
        self.rideName = rideName
        self.distanceKm = distanceKm
        self.duration = duration
        self.rideDateTime = rideDateTime
        self.uploadDateTime = uploadDateTime
        self.gpxHash = gpxHash
        self.ownerId = ownerId
        self.contextData = contextData
        self.ridePlottedMapPath = ridePlottedMapPath

    __tablename__ = "rideRecordingsTbl"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    rideGPXPath = db.Column(db.String(150))
    rideName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    distanceKm = db.Column(db.Float, server_default=text("0.0"))
    duration = db.Column(db.Time)
    rideDateTime = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    uploadDateTime = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    gpxHash = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    ownerId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usersTbl.id'), nullable=False)
    contextData = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=True)
    ridePlottedMapPath = db.Column(db.String(150))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Ride "{self.rideName[:20]}...">'

class Challenge(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, challengeName=None, challengeTargetDistanceKm=None, challengeCurrentTotalDistanceKm=None, challengeStarts=None, challengeEnds=None, createdByUserId=None, isActive=False, contextData=None, challengeLogoPath=None):
        self.challengeName = challengeName
        self.challengeTargetDistanceKm = challengeTargetDistanceKm
        self.challengeCurrentTotalDistanceKm = challengeCurrentTotalDistanceKm
        self.challengeStarts = challengeStarts
        self.challengeEnds = challengeEnds
        self.createdByUserId = createdByUserId
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.contextData = contextData
        self.challengeLogoPath = challengeLogoPath

    __tablename__ = "challengesTbl"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    challengeName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    challengeTargetDistanceKm = db.Column(db.Float, server_default=text("0.0"))
    challengeCurrentTotalDistanceKm = db.Column(db.Float, server_default=text("0.0"))
    challengeStarts = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    challengeEnds = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    createdByUserId = db.Column(db.Integer)
    isActive = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    contextData = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=True)
    challengeLogoPath = db.Column(db.String(150))

    mileage = db.relationship('MileagePerChallenge', back_populates='challenge', lazy=True)
    users = association_proxy('mileage', 'usersTbl')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Challenge "{self.challengeName[:20]}...">'

class MileagePerChallenge(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, userId=1, challengeId=1, challengeName=None, totalDistancePerChallengeKm=None, contextData=None):
        self.challengeName = challengeName
        self.userId = userId
        self.challengeId = challengeId
        self.totalDistancePerChallengeKm = totalDistancePerChallengeKm
        self.contextData = contextData

    __tablename__ = "mileagePerchallengesTbl"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    userId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usersTbl.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    challengeId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('challengesTbl.id'), nullable=False, index=True)

    challengeName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    totalDistancePerChallengeKm = db.Column(db.Float, server_default=text("0.0"))
    contextData =  db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=True)

    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='mileage', lazy=True)
    challenge = db.relationship('Challenge', back_populates='mileage', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<DistancePerChallenge "{self.challengeName[:20]}...">'


